# Blank White Screen After Install

Tags: php, silverstripe

I did a new clean install on my web host using softacolous.  When access my domain (url) all I get is a white blank screen. Also the admin has to go through index.php. What are the possible solutions to this problem? Silverstripe version is 3.1.15.  My other Silverstripe installation on the same host works fine.

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is do a dev/build then reload page.